# Overlay Div On Top of Img at Precise Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, svg, html5-canvas

I have checked other posts but none mentioned about a precise location to overlay.

Consider that I have an image, for eg. a traffic light. I need to overlay (not sure if this is the correct term or not) a div on top of the precise location of, the green lamp, for example. This is so that I can animate the div via jQuery to change the colour of the div in order to have an effect that the image is being animated.

The problem now is how to be precise in this, so that the location of the div completely matches that part of the image? Does it mean having to measure the pixels before setting the top and left of the divs? Or is there a smarter way?
I have considered other options such as using canvas (or svg, or silverlight) to redraw the whole thing instead of embedding the image (i.e. redraw a whole new traffic light picture). However, for this I believe it will be way more complicated than what I asked. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Please advise.

Comment: yes, you can do it that way.

Comment: @jimmyweb, thanks my friend, but which way were you referring to?

Comment: I was talking about div over image

Comment: @jimmyweb, yes, i know it can be done this way. My question is about placing a div at the exact position on top of the img. This is to prevent misalignment when viewed in different browsers and devices. If top and left cannot guarantee the placement, then would the alternatives as stated be wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to put the image inside a div which is either positioned relative if you want it to be inline with other elements or positioned absolute if you want to set its position on the page. Then position absolutely the overlapping div inside the same div as the image.

for example

Styles

```
#holder {
    position:relative;
}

#over {
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    left:20px;
    top:30px;
}
```

Body

```
<div id='holder'>
    <img src='IMAGE SOURCE'>
    <div id='over'></div>
</div>
```

You will need to adjust the width, height, left and top of the div with id='over' as necessary.

You could replace the div with id='over' with an image use position absolute on this image and set left and top as needed.

Comment: thanks, you mean that exact positioning still has to be adjusted/done manually, right?

Comment: Yes, a little bit of systematic trial and error should get you the values you need.

Comment: So, basically, the other alternatives (which includes re-drawing everything) are not so suitable?

Comment: Editing a base traffic light image into various combinations of lights and saving these different images as Tl1, TL2 etc., for example is another possibility. This way all images will be same size. Then pre-loading the images and swapping the src of the displayed image as needed is another option.

Comment: in this case it will still boil down to manually setting the top and left of those "hotspots". Appreciate your alternative view, anyway.